# Programmatically submitting a form in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, forms, post

Just started playing with Google App Engine & Python (as an excuse ;)).
How do I correctly submit a form like this

```
<form action="https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="ENTER_YOUR_USER_EMAIL@MERCHANT.COM">
<input type="hidden" name="status_url"
<!-- etc. -->
<input type="submit" value="Pay!">
</form>
```

w/o exposing the data to user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).

Here's an example of POSTing from the library's docs:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
>>> print f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

By hiding the sensitive bits of the form and submitting it via JavaScript.

Make sure you have a good way of referring to the form element...

```
<form ... id="moneybookersForm">...</form>
```

... and on page load, execute something like

```
document.getElementById("moneybookersForm").submit();
```

At least I don't know of other ways. For JavaScript-disabled people, the Pay! button should be kept visible.

Comment: He's asking for a solution in Python, not in Javascript.

Comment: I was just guessing this was what he wanted. As far as I know, there's no way of submitting a form in server-side Python and still let the user-agent see the resulting page.

Comment: No, but you can forward the result on to the client.