# How do I post to a Django 1.2 form using urllib?

Tags: django, django-forms

Going off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699238/programmatically-submitting-a-form-in-python) other SO question, I tried to use urlencode and urlopen to POST data to a form.  However, Django 1.2 gives me a CSRF verification failed error when I use it.  Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference between submitting data to other forms and your case is that you will have to first get the CSRF token. This can be done by performing a GET request on the page first and then parsing the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` using a suitable parser.

Also keep in mind that you'll need to install a cookie jar to get this to work.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

url = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/')
html = url.read()

doc = BeautifulSoup(html)
csrf_input = doc.find(attrs = dict(name = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'))
csrf_token = csrf_input['value']

params = urllib.urlencode(dict(username = 'foo', password='top_secret', 
       csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrf_token))
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/', params)
print url.read()
```

Comment: I tried your code above, but i get the following error (in the html) Please log in again, because your session has expired. Do you know how to keep alive the session? (I tried it with localhost:8000/admin)

Comment: Add `opener.addheaders = [('Referer', login_url)]`.  At least some Django deployments will require a _Referer_ header as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082128/how-do-i-authenticate-a-urllib2-script-in-order-to-access-https-web-services-fro)

Answer (score 1):

use the [csrf_exempt](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/#exceptions) decorator for the view that is handling the request

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```