# Ajax + Django: how to properly send few things from client browser to server?

Tags: ajax, django, post, extjs, request

In my app, there are several categories of data that need to be sent from client browser to server. 
the back end is in Django. I am trying to using Ajax to POST data to the view function in Django, and then return something to client. The codes I've tried are as follows:

**In Django urls.py:**

```
 (r'^testPost/', testPost),
```

**Django View function:**

```
def testPost(request):
    print request
    if request.method == 'GET':
        rID = request.GET['rID']
        rName = request.GET['rName'] 
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        rID = request.POST['rID']
        rName = request.POST['rName'] 

    return HttpResponse("ID: " + str(rID) + " and Name: " + str(rName))
```

**Front-end AJAX call (ExtJS 3.3):**

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({ 
        url: 'XXXX/testPost/?',
        method: 'POST',
        jsonData: Ext.encode({
            "rID": 1333,
                    "rName": 'test'
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function (response, opts){
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }, 
                failure:function (response, opts){
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                } 
});
```

It seems something is wrong with URL setting.  got an error response:

```
Some unexpected error occurred. Error text was: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN
```

**UPDATE:**
1. based on ldiqual's advice, put

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
```

in the view script

1. changed ExtJS ajax request code from using jsonData to params:

   **params: {
          "rID": 1333,
           "rName": 'test'
   }**

issue is solved for my case.

Comment: POST requires CSRF token

Comment: In addition to what A. Vasinov said, you can avoid the CSRF check by decorating your view with `@csrf_exempt`.

Comment: thanks you too, and especially Idiqual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ajax POSTing, you'll need CSRF token, and it's unwise to simply disable it with `@csrf_exempt` since it defeats the purpose. If you don't want CSRF protection, then remove `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` from MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

The Django docs provide a jQuery function that will automatically add the token to all ajax requests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

I don't have any experience with ExtJS, but you'll want to find an equivalent. Here are some snippets you could look at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485616/338903
- http://djbook.ru/examples/22/
- [http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134125-Django-1.3-Login-with-ExtJS-4-and-CSRF](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134125-Django-1.3-Login-with-ExtJS-4-and-CSRF&p=608348&viewfull=1#post608348)

Answer (score 0):

In your template file (assume that you use jQuery library):

```
<form id="MyForm" action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" class="default" value="Save" onclick="PostThisToAjax(jQuery("#MyForm").serialize()); return false;" />
</form>
```

Comment: interesting.. i am not even sure about whether this is the cause. first of all, i am not dealing with form submission, but a pure ajax request from front-end. and I did use a proxy in server to solve this corss-domain request issue. then according to Idiqual's advice, I put @csrf_exempt in that Django view script, and changed ExtJS ajax code from using jsonData to params, then it all works well now...

Comment: By default Django requires CSRF token for **every** POST. Could you use GET instead?