# Django - Post ajax request forbidden 403 with ExtJS

Tags: ajax, django, extjs

I am using ExtJs to create a button that do an ajax post to my django application, but the post is blocked by a FORBIDDEN (403) error.

I tryed to pass the CSRF token in as POST data by setting a custom X-CSRFToken header to the value of the CSRF token (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) without success

ExtJS.js

```
        action =  new Ext.Button({
            text: 'Ajax Test',
            handler: function () {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'test/',
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                        params: {'test': 'test'},
                        success: function(response, opts) {
                                var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                console.dir(obj);
                                },
                        failure: function(response, opts) {
                                console.log('server-side failure');
                                }
                });
            },
         });
```

view.py

```
def test(request):
    print "TEST WORKING"
    print dict(request.POST.copy().iteritems())
    return HttpResponse("")
```

---

CHROME NETWORK TAB:

Response:

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

Cookies:

```
Request Cookies:
csrftoken  :  S7uLgmhqeprWqL4NdH9mznIfpTgyM9RP
djdt  :  hide
djdttop  :  30
sessionid  :  sx4ukmkitqp39wvuve1a9zed2kjiwfb1

Response Cookies:
(empty)
```

Headers:

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/basqui/layer/edit/2/test/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 FORBIDDEN
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:sessionid=sx4ukmkitqp39wvuve1a9zed2kjiwfb1; csrftoken=S7uLgmhqeprWqL4NdH9mznIfpTgyM9RP; djdttop=30; djdt=hide
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/basqui/layer/edit/2
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
test:test
Response Headersview source
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 07 Jan 2014 16:52:15 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.5
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: Show us the django view as well..

Comment: Adding the CSRF-token is the correct solution, can you please add it again, then do the request and copy/paste the post and response from your browsers dev tools network tab?

Comment: habitually the ajax post is working when adding the CSRF-token. I think its not working here because the ajax is initialized through extJS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include Django 1.2's CSRF token in a Javascript-generated HTML form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764589/how-do-i-include-django-1-2s-csrf-token-in-a-javascript-generated-html-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        action =  new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Ajax Test',
        handler: function () {
            var csrf = Ext.util.Cookies.get('csrftoken');
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'test/',
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    params: {'test': 'test', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf},
                    success: function(response, opts) {
                            var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            console.dir(obj);
                            },
                    failure: function(response, opts) {
                            console.log('server-side failure');
                            }
            });
        },
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134125-Django-1-3-Login-with-ExtJS-4-and-CSRF

I put this in my Application launch function:

```
Ext.require(["Ext.util.Cookies", "Ext.Ajax"], function(){
    // Add csrf token to every ajax request
    var token = Ext.util.Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    if(!token){
        Ext.Error.raise("Missing csrftoken cookie");
    } else {
        Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = Ext.apply(Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders || {}, {
            'X-CSRFToken': token
        });
    }
});
```