# Is there any idea that i can put closing tag(/>) in text input tag of html in django form processing?

Tags: django

//here is form in django code

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

//now the form is rendered as

```
<input type="text" name="phone_email" required id="id_phone_email">
 <input type="text" name="full_name" required id="id_full_name">
```

//now this html code doesn't have any input field closing tag(/>) any i am being able to run the jsx code because of the absence of closing input tag.any idea how can i put closing tag(/>) in django??

Comment: `input` does not have closing tag. Your issue is something else https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: I know that it's optional, but react jsx doesn't work without that...Now i am in trouble.so please any idea?

Comment: The markup rendered by django is correct. You need to use `/>` with the javascript for react.

Comment: I'm confused. How is the rendered form interfering with jsx? They should not have direct interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override how a form renders the HTML for its input fields, you could create a custom form widget.

```
from django.forms.widgets import Input

class JSXInput(Input):
    template_name = 'myapp/widgets/jsxinput.html'
```

And add this widget to your form field:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(widget=JSXInput)
```

Then you can crib off of the `django/forms/widgets/input.html` template in the `django.forms.templates` module and add your closing brace.

```
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" .... />
```

This was for Django 2, but iirc it is pretty similar in 1.11.

**However**, you should ask yourself whether or not your JSX code should be rendered by Django, or instead be a static asset that then talks to a Django REST API.

Comment: It's really working ..thanks a lot mr #bruno_desthuilliers....can i ask another issue please...i need to customise the csrf input filed also so any idea about that ?

Comment: You should be able to generate that one by hand by using the `csrf_token` in the context. Take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764652/616950]