# Preserve csrf token while reading a web page

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf, django-1.7

I have a partial view and I provide it on some url with:

```
url(r'^main.html$', PartialGroupView.as_view(template_name='main.html'), name='main')
```

I  am trying to read that url elsewhere in the code with:

```
partial = urllib2.urlopen(partial_url).read()
```

And than I want to send it to the user like:

```
return HttpResponse(partial)
```

And everything is working fine, but the problem is that the page contains a csrf token and afterwards, when the user gets the page that is sent to him, he tries to submit a form, but when he does, an error is thrown, saying that the token is missing or incorrect. On step one, if I use only this method to send the view to the user, than the token is working correctly.

So is there any way to preserve that token when I read the page in this way? Or is there any other way to read the page without violating the csrf?

**Personal solution:**

In my case I decided that there would be a better approach to this and gave up on reading the html from a url. I just send the partial this way:

```
render(request, demanded_partial_name)
```

since it is available locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option is to make the view CSRF exempt, as seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt).

A most likely better idea is to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623925/how-do-i-post-to-a-django-1-2-form-using-urllib) SO post.  Basically, what you're doing is passing in a dictionary of parameters when you encode the url, and that dictionary will contain the csrf middleware token.

Comment: I eventually turned to another solution, but your answer helped me figure it out, and it is a valid approach, so thanks. (:

Comment: Glad I could help.  It might be good to add the solution you came up with in case anyone else comes across this question with the same problem you're having.